# suitCRM workflow - getting a field from another module to the new module

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need to get a field from a custom created module to contacts list view. I found that we can achieve it through the workflow. But I am new to workflow. Please help me to do this. I am using the latest version of SuiteCRM, 7.9.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a relationship between modules
2. Create a custom field in contact module
3. The got to workflow module and click on cerate workflow
4. click on Add a condition
5. Select your custom module, and field.
6. Select Operator as "Equal To"
7. Type "Any Change".
8. Then go to actions
9. select action as Modify record
10. Record type as related module
11. select the custom field which needs to be updated
12. select mapping field in custom module